# Is it possible merge android code in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want to make a Spin_Wheel game in flutter but some functions are not available
in the flutter, so can I use android for UI in the flutter.

Thank in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider it a no.

While it is possible to communicate using [platform_channels](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/) the texturized UI, to than display it in flutter ; this is too complicated.

Depending on your "functions", it is far better to recode them in dart. And you get IOS portability.